# Unable to figure out inplace operation in the pytorch code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following implementation in PyTorch for learning using LSTM:

https://gist.github.com/rahulbhadani/f1d64042cc5a80280755cac262aa48aa

However, the code is experiencing in-place operation error

where my error output is:

```
/home/ivory/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-560ec78f2b64> in <module>
     27 linear = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_nums, output_dim)
     28 
---> 29 global_loss_list = global_training(lstm2)

<ipython-input-84-152890a3028c> in global_training(optimizee)
      3     adam_global_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([{'params': optimizee.parameters()}, 
      4                                      {'params':linear.parameters()}], lr = 0.0001)
----> 5     _, global_loss_1 = learn2(LSTM_Optimizee, training_steps, retain_graph_flag=True, reset_theta=True)
      6 
      7     print(global_loss_1)

<ipython-input-83-0357a528b94d> in learn2(optimizee, unroll_train_steps, retain_graph_flag, reset_theta)
     43             # requires_grad=True. These are accumulated into x.grad for every
     44             # parameter x. In pseudo-code: x.grad += dloss/dx
---> 45             loss.backward(retain_graph = retain_graph_flag) #The default is False, when the optimized LSTM is set to True
     46 
     47             print('x.grad: {}'.format(x.grad))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    116                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    117         """
--> 118         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    119 
    120     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     91     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     92         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 93         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     94 
     95 

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 10]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I have tried to trace the error but didn't succeed. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with anomaly detection enabled?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I could not figure out what was going on.

Comment: Well, I learned pyTorch a week ago, so I still have to get accustomed to it. Things are a bit different from TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the following line:

```
global_loss_list.append(global_loss.detach_())
```

The convention in PyTorch for in-place operations is using `_` at the end of the function name (as in `detach_`). I believe you shouldn't be detaching in-place. In other words, change `detach_` to `detach`

Comment: So, does the answer fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I followed your suggestion and there are a few points I realized:
1. I forgot to add learn2() function in the GitHub gist provided above. So I added that and updated the gist.
2. I tried to run locally on my machine the updated code but it threw the same error, still don't know why, but, but when I ran on Google Colab, it runs perfectly. See Link to Google Colab file: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kjvdmaWpKr9PS-FTy-6lVw_j1sbQNs4Y

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with Google Colab itself or Pytorch version they are using vs what I am using. In my system, it is 1.2.0 and in Google Colab it is 1.1.0

Comment: Adding to your last comment @Andrew Naguib, it did fix my issue, but only on Google Colab, not locally.

Comment: And, line link in Andrew's answer needs to be updated, since I updated my GitHub gist.

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks!